# Fullcalendar - inverse-background

Tags: jquery, calendar, fullcalendar

I have integrated full calendar for resources. I am trying to set available time for each resource.
In place of setting resource available time, I am setting up unavailable time because of certain constraints.

When I use `inverse-background` in full calendar event, it takes up a whole week.
Can this property be set to be only for a day?

In [this `codepen` link](https://codepen.io/15jigar/pen/jpJxvQ?editors=0010#0) I have integrated the solution.

Any suggestions?

Comment: All I see in your codepen is a calendar widget with the current day being highlighted... It's not totally clear what your question is, please try to clarify it.

Comment: In the week view, I have used inverse-background to inverse the time for unavailability. Can it be set for a sing day only? means can inverse-background be set for just one day in place of whole week

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same question. The [documentation about **`inverse-background`**](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/background-events#inverse-backgrounds) said:

> The spans of time *not* occupied by an event can be colored by setting the display property to `inverse-background`

So I think the only option is to split the background event and set one part before and one after the actual event:

```js
events: [
 {
    start: '2018-08-15 00:00:00',
    end: '2018-08-15 12:00:00',
    allDay: false,
    rendering: 'background'
  },
  {
    start: '2018-08-15 15:00:00',
    end: '2018-08-15 23:59:59',
    allDay: false,
    rendering: 'background'
  },
```

That's the result (see here on [codepen](https://codepen.io/15jigar/pen/jpJxvQ)):

[image: screenshot]